# how to restrict duplicate data in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i just hit a demo api with link and created a dynamic table and in every click of parameter a new row is inserted with it, i just want to resitrict duplicate entry from table.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  //count = 1;
    var counter=1,flag=0;

           $("#api").click(function () {
             var index = ($("#para").val());
             if (index == "") {
              alert("Please input data");
              return false;
             }
             else{
              $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+index,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                       
                     var tr = [];
                    
                        if(flag==0){
                    mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable", class:"basicTable1" });

                       //for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                       let ab = $('<h1>API Data</h1>').appendTo("#h");
                       let row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                       let row1 = $('<tr id="row'+counter+'" ></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                       $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                      $('<th></th>').text(key).appendTo(row); 
                      $('<td></td>').text(val).appendTo(row1); 

                          });
                        let row2 = $('<button class="button1" id="button'+ counter+'" onclick=removeFun('+ counter+')>remove Row</button>').appendTo(row1);
                    flag=1;
                      counter++;
                      //}
                  mytable.appendTo("#data");

                     }
                    else{
                   //for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                   let row = $('<tr id="row'+counter+'" ></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  $('<td></td>').text(val).appendTo(row); 
                  });
                  let row1 = $('<button class="button1" id="button'+ counter+'" onclick=removeFun('+ counter+')>remove Row</button>').appendTo(row);
                  counter++;
                   //}
                       mytable.appendTo("#data");   
} 
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        alert("No Record Found");
                    }
                });

             }
                  
             });
       });
function removeFun(a){
$("#row"+a).remove();
}

 var textbox = $("#data");
  textbox.change(function() {
     $("#basicTable").find("td").each(function(){
        if($(this).html()==textbox.val()){
           alert(textbox.val());
        };
     })
  });
```

```css
.h1{
 color: orange;
 margin:30px;
}
.h2{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
table, th, td {
   border: 2.5px solid black;
   align-content: center;
}
table{
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
}
th{
 height: 50px;
 align-content: right;
 background-color: orange;
}
th:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}
th,td{
 width: 30%;
}
.button1 {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

.button1:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

.button1:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Api hit with JSON</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<center><u class="h1">AJAX</u> api with JSON</center>
<center>
 <div class="h2">
  <label>Enter the parameter</label>
  <input type="number" name="" id="para">
  <button id="api">Submit</button>
  </div>
 <div id="h"></div>
 <div id="data"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my file, I hit the demo api with link and get the data to dynamic table but I want to restrict duplicate files in the dynamic table.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    //count = 1;
    var counter=1,flag=0;

           $("#api").click(function () {
                var index = ($("#para").val());
                if (index == "") {
                    alert("Please input data");
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+index,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);

                        var tr = [];

                        if(flag==0){
                    mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable", class:"basicTable1" });

                       //for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                       let ab = $('<h1>API Data</h1>').appendTo("#h");
                       let row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                       let row1 = $('<tr id="row'+counter+'" ></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                       $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                      $('<th></th>').text(key).appendTo(row); 
                      $('<td></td>').text(val).appendTo(row1); 

                          });
                        let row2 = $('<button class="button1" id="button'+ counter+'" onclick=removeFun('+ counter+')>remove Row</button>').appendTo(row1);
                    flag=1;
                      counter++;
                      //}
                  mytable.appendTo("#data");

                     }
                    else{
                   //for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                   let row = $('<tr id="row'+counter+'" ></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  $('<td></td>').text(val).appendTo(row); 
                  });
                  let row1 = $('<button class="button1" id="button'+ counter+'" onclick=removeFun('+ counter+')>remove Row</button>').appendTo(row);
                  counter++;
                   //}
                       mytable.appendTo("#data");   
} 
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        alert("No Record Found");
                    }
                });

                }

             });
       });
function removeFun(a){
$("#row"+a).remove();
}
```

Comment: can you put your "data" here

Comment: You should manipulate data before creating table.

Comment: @SumeshTG no, it is genertated from this link https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

Comment: @NegiRox here is link of data https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

Comment: @AbhijeetSrivastava Please include your html and make it as snippet.

Comment: @SumeshTG all done

Answer (score 0):

first you need to remove duplicates from your "data"

```
   var GroupByColumn = function (SourceData, columnName) {
    var Unique = {};
    var groupByColumn = columnName;
    var tempData = SourceData;
    for (var i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
       if (!Unique[tempData[i][groupByColumn]])
        Unique[tempData[i][groupByColumn]] = [];
       Unique[tempData[i][groupByColumn]].push(tempData[i]);
   }
  return Unique;
}
```

by using above function you can find a unique data

```
var z= [
          {
         "userId": 1,
         "id": 1,
         "title": "delectus aut autem",
         "completed": false
         },
         {
          "userId": 1,
          "id": 2,
          "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
          "completed": false
        }
]
GroupByColumn(z,"id")
GroupByColumn(z,"title")
GroupByColumn(z,"completed")
GroupByColumn(z,"userId")
```

depepends on your need it will return your data. hope this will be helpful

Comment: how to call this function

Comment: what is your expected result. because using GroupByColumn(z,"userId") I can find a group of array with 20 element in each